# On view hierarchy, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, ios, view

In this code example, i am trying to produce the following view hierarchy

> Window -> background image -> scroll view -> text view

All i see however is

> Window -> background image

What am i missing please?

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UIScrollView *scrollWindow = [[UIScrollView alloc] 
                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 440, 212)];

    UITextView *scrollableText = [[UITextView alloc] init];

    [scrollableText setEditable:NO];
    [scrollableText setText:@"Why, hello there"];

    [scrollWindow addSubview:scrollableText];

    UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"about_bg.png"].CGImage];
    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
             initWithImage:backgroundImage];

    [backgroundView addSubview:scrollWindow];

    [[self view] addSubview:backgroundView];

}
```

Comment: UITextView is already a subclass of UIScrollView. Are you sure you need one more scroll view in the hierarchy?

Comment: @Davyd, Thank you. I did not realize this before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew is right about not making the scroll view a subview of the background `UIImageView` view. But the scroll view *is* invisible. Only its content (`scrollableText`) will show. And you haven't set `scrollableText`'s frame, so it's effectively invisible too. Init like so:

```
[scrollableText setEditable:NO];
[scrollableText setText:@"Why, hello there"];
[scrollableText setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
```

And you should see it.

Comment: Good call on frame of the text view. But on views ... are you saying that both scrollview and background image view should be equal in hierarchy?

Comment: Yes (edited by answer to make that a little more clear). It might work, and this may be a stylistic thing, but the way I see it: `UIImageView`'s layers and subviews are an implementation detail. It does something non-specific and undocumented to display an image. Who knows how this will interact with user-added subviews now and in the future? This combined with odd behavior like it never calls `-drawRect:` and user interaction with it is *disabled* by default, and I feel it's safer to composite views on top of `UIImageView`s rather than messing with their hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this hierarchy:

```
Window
  background image view
  scroll view
    text view
```

Try adding two subviews to your window, not shove them all as subviews into each other.''-

```
   - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

      UIScrollView *scrollWindow = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 440, 212)];

      UITextView *scrollableText = [[UITextView alloc] init];

      UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"about_bg.png"]];

      scrollableText.editable = NO;
      scrollableText.text = @"Why, hello there";

      [scrollWindow addSubview:scrollableText];

      [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
      [self.view addSubview:scrollWindow];
    }
```